CORS error between Docker containers in EC2
I am deploying a university project with Docker Compose on an EC2 machine. I have 2 Docker containers: one for the frontend (coded in Vuejs) and one for the backend (coded in Java Spring Boot).
When I launched the containers locally, everything worked correctly, but when I run them on my EC2, although I manage to connect the backend container to the RDS, when I make requests from the frontend I get a CORS error, indicating that it does not recognize the hostname.
The problem comes in that I have explicitly specified the hostname of both services in my docker-compose.yml. I have also created a network to connect both services, and verified that when launching the containers they are within the same network.
To test if the hostname resolves I have tried the following:
docker exec -it docker-frontend ping tfgbackend
docker exec -it docker-backend ping tfgfrontend
The first parameter would be the container name and the second would be the hostname I specified in the docker-compose.yml file. Both commands return a successful ping.
docker exec -it docker-frontend nslookup tfgbackend
In this case it does return an NXDOMAIN error, indicating that the hostname does not resolve.
As I understand it, within a docker-compose services can reach each other using the name of the other service or, in my case, the specified hostname. However, it seems that in this case it fails to resolve the hostname.
Finally, the relevant configuration regarding CORS that I am using is as follows:

The ports exposed in docker-compose.yml are 8080 for the frontend and 8000 for the backend.

On the frontend I make requests to the backend using Axios, with the URL http://tfgbackend:8000.

In the backend I have included the @CrossOrigin(origins = “http://tfgfrontend:8080”) annotation in all REST controllers.


Given this situation, what could be causing this CORS error?

A browser application doesn't actually run in a container, even if its code is served from a container.  I'm a little surprised you're getting a CORS error and not something else; I'd expect the browser application to not be able to resolve the hostname tfgbackend.  Does "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend solve your problem?  Of note, the Nginx proxy configuration there would not make cross-origin calls.  If not, can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?
